# help-popup on chat is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, chat, help-text

I wanted to know how to format stuff in chat, and clicked the *help* link. There was this popup:

[image: screenshot]

Shows that it does not fit in my browser window, and also is not scrollable (if I scroll, it only scrolls the chat content). This has these effects:

- I can't fully read the text, since the top some lines are hidden. This is not the biggest problem, since the [more](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) link at the bottom gives me the full text.
- I can't close the popup, since the close button is outside the window ... I tried <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but no reaction here. I finally had the idea to switch to full screen mode, where it barely fits, and then I could close this popup.

It may be that I simply have a too small screen. But I recently upgraded my resolution from 800×600 to 1024×768 pixels (and my graphics card does not support more).

Could there be something done to fit this on smaller screens, too? Or maybe simply making it scrollable?

This is in Opera 11.50 on Ubuntu 11.04, if this matters. My browser window (the content area) is 665 pixels height, says kruler.

Comment: By my eye it is a shade under 700px high (including the bottom bar etc), but it can probably be a tiny bit shorter.... but not by much! (not much is wrapped there)

Answer (score 3):

Squeezed it down a bit (mainly columnizing the bullets, but made it *slightly* wider too) - the Cogs of Deploy™ are turning now; any better?

Comment: I'm now at another computer, I'll check it next night.